# How to check a list or feed of all posts under a category and tag?

Tags: query-posts, query

Consider this question from the point-of-view of a visitor to a WordPress blog, and not as a WordPress blog admin who can edit those numerous PHP files.

How can I see a list of all the posts under a category and a tag? Not clear? Let me explain with an example:

> I have two categories -- *Social Media (social)* and *Web (web)*, and
>   I have a tag *Tips and Tricks (tips-and-tricks)*.
>
> Consider that I use the tag frequently with posts under both
>   categories. The question is, how can a visitor to my blog, check posts
>   tagged "tips-and-tricks" and under "social" category?

I am looking for a solution *similar to* this: `http://example.com/feed/?cat=11,12` (which we use to combine rss feeds of multiple categories). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! Similar to how you'd do it with RSS feeds, you can do it like this:

`http://example.com/?cat=6&tag=tips-and-tricks`

Where `6` is the category ID of *Social Media (social)* category as per the example.

Comment: Did you know that you can and may accept your own answer as correct? It is actually encouraged to do so - further readers will not attempt to answer your question and ppl with a similar problem are more likely to look closely and find help.

Comment: @JohannesPille Yes, I do know that. But I can only do so after 2 days. :) That's how StackExchange sites' flood control works, I guess.